# Mac Mail - move IMAP message to Exchange folder

Tags: mac, email, exchange, imap

In Mac mail I have most of my email accounts set up
Hotmail, Gmail, Yahoo, and Exchange (office365 hosted).

When I try to move any of my messages from the first 3 (all IMAP accounts) into my Exchange Folder (where I archive everything), it gives me the error can't move message.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Which is the exact error message?

Comment: It may not answer the exact question you asked, but I use MigrationWiz - https://www.bittitan.com/products/#migrationwiz - when Mail gives me issues.  In my professional experience, it's not worth the time it would take you to diagnose and troubleshoot the issue.  Pay MigrationWiz like $12 and have them move what you want.  Done.  In the hours you'll save, you can make a lot more than that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is causing the error, but I can tell you where on the filesystem you can find your messages. Perhaps you can move them manually in Finder?

The default location for mailboxes is:

`~/Library/Mail/V2/`

in Finder, choose **Go To Folder** from the **GO** menu or use the shortcut `⬆︎⌘G` and paste that path into the dialog box.  That folder should contain folders for each of your mail accounts, each containing mailbox folders with labels like `INBOX.mbox` which are simply folders themselves. You'll likely have to traverse down several levels of folders with arbitrary names before you reach a `Data` folder containing a `Messages` folder which is where you will finally find your email messages. Hope that helps you out.